# Add decimals separator to numbers

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google sheet column with product prices but due to an error the decimals separator is missing. So I've got 15656 instead of 156.56

How do I add a period before the last two numbers in every single price on that column?

Comment: Does `Format > Number > Currency` not fix this?

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use [CONCATENATE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094123?hl=en):

`=CONCATENATE(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-2),".",RIGHT(A1,2))`

[image: example]

---

If you want to apply this to the full column:

`=arrayformula(IF(A1:A<>"",LEFT(A1:A,LEN(A1:A)-2) & "." & RIGHT(A1:A,2),""))`

[image: example2]

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(TEXT(A1:A, "#.00"))
```

Answer (score 0):

In your question you do not clarify whether your data cells are formatted as text or numbers.
The following covers both cases.

Your basic formula would be

```
=REGEXREPLACE(TEXT(B2,"0"),"()(\d{1,2})$","$1.$2")*1
```

If you need to apply it to more than 1 rows you can either drag it down or  use an arrayformula instead.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(B2:B12), 
       REGEXREPLACE(TEXT(B2:B12,"0"),"()(\d{1,2})$","$1.$2")*1,""))
```

[image: Add decimals separator to numbers]

---

**Advantages over other solutions**

1. Works on both text formatted cells as well as number formatted ones.
2. Always produces results as a number (ready for further calculations)
3. Leaves no *residue* on blank cells.
4. Can be easily formatted to currency (or any other number format) through the top menu.

Functions used:

- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`IF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)
- [`LEN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094081)
- [`REGEXREPLACE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245)
- [`TEXT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139)